# Testing AMD modules with tape/ES6 unit tests?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, amd, node.js-tape

I have a web app using:

- ES5
- RequireJS
- Underscore
- Backbone
- jQuery

I have tried setting up a new unit test suite using:

- ES6
- Tape
- Babel6

My AMD module app/util/stringUtil.js:

```
define([], function() {
    'use strict';

    return {
        isBlank: function(str) {
            return _.isUndefined(str) || _.isNull(str) || _.isString(str) && str.trim().length === 0;
        }
    };
});
```

My unit test in tapeTest.js:

```
import test from 'tape';
import sortUtil from 'app/util/stringUtil';

test('Testing stringUtil', (assert) => {

    assert.ok(stringUtil.isBlank('   ')),
        'Should be blank');

    assert.end();
});
```

My .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

I run the test with tape:

```
tape -r babel-register tapeTest.js
```

I get the following error:

```
app/util/stringUtil.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { define([], function () {
                                                              ^
ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (stringUtil.js:1:23)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at loader (node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:126:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:136:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (tapeTest.js:7:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
```

I'm guessing tape doesn't recognize AMD modules? Can I fix this somehow? Maybe transpile AMD modules to CommonJS modules or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load AMD modules inside node with requirejs :_)

Read here: http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html

You have to import require and do a little config, something like this:

```
'use strict';

const test = require('tape');
const requirejs = require('requirejs');

requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: __dirname,
    nodeRequire: require
});

test('Test something', function (assert) {
    requirejs(['app/util/stringUtil'], function   (stringUtil) {

        assert.ok(stringUtil.isBlank('   '), 'Should be blank');

        assert.end();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using karma, webpack and phantomjs launcher:

- karma
- karma-webpack
- karma-phantomjs-launcher
- karma-tap
- tape

Webpack transpiles the ES6 unit tests to ES5 modules and karma launches and runs the tests in a phantomjs browser.